# How to output image with baseline format using imagemagick?

Tags: php, imagemagick, baseline, progressive

Output only progressive image format with scaleImage() and writeImage() imagemagick functions.
Thanks.

Comment: Any code you would like to share so we can see what you are doing?

Comment: This is my code fragment, thanks for your answer!!...
http://prnt.sc/cwwxnj

Answer (score 0):

Your question is hard to understand, but I think you want a baseline JPEG and not an interlaced one.

If that is the case, all you need to do is remove the line:

```
$image->setInterlaceScheme(IMagick::INTERLACE_LINE);
```

Comment: When open in photoshop, the format option is progressive. :-( 
http://prnt.sc/cx6faj

Comment: Those are your **Save** options. The file itself is progressive. Try `identify -verbose image.jpg` and look for `Interlace:`